# Android - when i lose intenetconnection my Asynktask stopps/finish, i want it to "pause" until connect=ok, what is the best way?

Tags: java, android, networking, android-asynctask, connection

i have a application that start a asynktask.
in the asynktask i call a class to connect to a server, and this connectclass throws MessagingException, IOException..

if I loose intenetconnection, the class throws the Exception.

and asynktask catch this.

today when it receive a Exception, i only logg this and "end the asynktask.."

I want it to "pause" so when i have a connection I un-pause this.. (end not end this)
but I do not know how, can you help me please?

code today (edited):

```
.....
    protected Void doInBackground(String... Buffer) {
                        while (!match && getAsynkOKStatus){
                            try {  
                        nameBuffer = Buffer [0];
                        NrBuffer = Buffer [1];

                        ServerConnect ServerSearch1 = new ServerConnect();

                        if ( ServerSearch1.isMatch(nameBuffer, NrBuffer) ){
                            Content = "wow MATCH";                      
                            match = true;
                        }

                    } catch (MessagingException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                        SetAsynkOKStatus(false);
                        Content = "nopp.. error";
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                        SetAsynkOKStatus(false);
                        Content = "nopp.. IO-error";
                    }                   
               }//endwhile

                    return null;
    }
//more code..
......
```

Comment: You are wrongly designing your asynctask. This is not the way to do it. Please understand what you want do then Design your solution in object oriented manner.What you have done is totally waste.Please code like a good engineer.

Comment: ok, thank you for your reply..
I can rephrase the question:
If i have a working asynktask that read from the server, and then i get a "no network - fault" I want this to pause, is this possible?
if not: should i use a "start alarm manager" and then start a service, that read "the server"?